# Data types with holes

Tags: haskell, types, abstract-data-type

So if I have two data types which are mostly the same, I can write them like this:

```
data A t = A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 (B t)
data B t = B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 t

type AX = A X
type AY = A Y
```

Now it's easy to write functions over AX and AY, or 'A t' if they don't care.  But then how do I write a conversion?

```
convert :: AX -> AY
convert (A4 (B4 x)) = A4 (B4 (xToY x))
convert ax = ay -- type error
```

So now I need to write all the other cases out by hand, even though none of them depend on the type parameter.  What's worse, while I can match a constructor without depending on the arguments with 'A {}', that's not possible if I need those arguments to reconstruct the data.

Is there a nicer way to do this?  I feel like GADTs should be able to express this but it's hard to see how to eliminate the type variable from the terms that don't depend on it.  I think I'd have to have separate types for A1 A2 etc. and then I'd lose the closed-ness and case checking... besides I don't want to write Show, Eq, and Typeable by hand!  The only other way I can think of is to rearrange the whole structure to isolate the changing part i.e.

```
data A t = Independent | B4 t
data Independent = A1 | A2 | ...
```

But this makes every other use of the data awkward for the benefit of one conversion function.

Of course, yet another option is to forget about type safety and include 'B4 (Either X Y)' and put in some nice runtime errors for when it has the wrong value.

Maybe there's a better way to approach "almost the same" data types?

Update: so I worked around by writing a pseudo-fmap:

```
convert :: (a -> b) -> A a -> A b
```

Which at least allows me to separate the conversion part and the packing-unpacking boilerplate.  I guess a sufficiently advanced bit of TH could probably generate one of those for me.  I'm still curious about other approaches though.  I feel like this way is still not precise, because it allows the hole to be filled with *anything* while what I really mean is exactly one of two things.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're after, but I've updated my answer with regards to only allowing `A` and `B` to be used with certain types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like basically what you want is for `A` and `B` to be `Functor`s. Fortunately, you can allow Haskell to derive the obvious `Functor` instances for these types, using `-XDeriveFunctor`. Then, use this code:

```
data A t = A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 (B t) deriving Functor
data B t = B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 t deriving Functor
```

...

```
convert :: AX -> AY
convert a = fmap xToY a
```

Here's a sample GHCi session after adding some dummy definitions for `X`, `Y` and `xToY`, as well as having everything derive `Show`:

```
*Main> convert $ A4 B1
A4 B1
*Main> convert $ A4 (B4 X)
A4 (B4 Y)
*Main> convert $ A2
A2
```

#### Update

If you really want to only allow `A` and `B` to be "filled" with things of type `X` or `Y`, you could constrain them like so:

```
class XorY t where

instance XorY X
instance XorY Y

data XorY t => A t = A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 (B t)
data XorY t => B t = B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 t
```

Of course this will preclude the possibility of making `A` and `B` `Functor`s, so the trick outlined above won't work any more.

Comment: Hah, right you are, for some reason I thought deriving would choke on a nested data type.  I think I'll stick with my hand-written version because I want to convert from a specific type to a specific type, not advertise global membership in anything to anything, but it's much lighter weight than some TH hairball.

Comment: Well, and classes are open.  I could not export the class, but that doesn't really provide anything that I couldn't do by just only exporting the type synonyms and not the original data structure.  But it's ok, because I can't think of anything neat the compiler could do for me if it knew that.  This is one of those things extensible records would be nice for.